# Python: How to import arules package from R using Rpy2

Tags: python-3.x, rpy2

I am trying to use python with some nice functions in R. In particular I want to use read.transactions function which is found in one of the packages in R (arules)

I did the following steps

1- Open Anaconda and lunch R studio

### In R studio

2- install.packages('arules', dep = TRUE)
3- loadNamespace('arules')

4- .libPaths()

Got

```
[1] "D:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2/R/win-library/3.4"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library"
```

Now I go to jupyter notebook

### In Jupyter Notebook

```
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as RObjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr("utils")


d = {'print.me': 'print_dot_me', 'print_me': 'print_uscore_me'}
try:
    arules = importr('arules', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "D:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2/R/win-library/3.4")
except:
    arules = importr('arules', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library")
```

The Outcome was

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5df30d28440c> in <module>()
      3 try:
----> 4     arules = importr('arules', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "D:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2/R/win-library/3.4")
      5 except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'arules'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5df30d28440c> in <module>()
      4     arules = importr('arules', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "D:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2/R/win-library/3.4")
      5 except:
----> 6     arules = importr('arules', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library")
      7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'arules'
```

Which was not able to import the R package to Python

I did the same with `DirichletReg` and it was successful. I do not know why.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now to the last of the discovery, there is nothing like that in python, however, there is a way out to use `read.transactions`

```
groceries <- read.transactions("groceries.csv", sep = ",")
> summary(groceries)
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
9835 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
169 columns (items) and a density of 0.02609146
```

## Python Jupyter notebook

1) Import the data as

```
import requests
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/groceries.csv'
grocery_dataset = requests.get(url)
# Save string as txt file
f = open('grocery_dataset.txt','w')
f.write(grocery_dataset.text)
f.close()
```

2) Separate the data and adjust them as you wish

```
import csv
grocery_items = set()
with open("grocery_dataset.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        grocery_items.update(line)
output_list = list()
with open("grocery_dataset.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        row_val = {item:0 for item in grocery_items}
        row_val.update({item:1 for item in line})
        output_list.append(row_val)
```

4) save it as a Dataframe in python

```
import pandas as pd
grocery_df = pd.DataFrame(output_list)
```

hence

```
grocery_df.shape
```

will give

```
(9835, 169)
```

which represent that of the rows and columns of the `summary(groceries)` in R

Answer (score 1):

importr looks into R_HOME directory for the installed R packages. I assume, arules package was not added in the library folder of R_HOME instead it is added in some other location let's say 'C:\Users\User_name\Documents\R\win-library\3.x.x' which might be causing the issue.

If that is the case, copy arules folder from that specific location and add into library folder of R_HOME directory. Try this approach and see whether you are able to come out of the problem.